# Is there a way to open an electron app from another electron app?

Tags: reactjs, electron

I currently have an Electron app project and i want to create another electron + react project in which there would be a button on home page along with other pages and functionality and on clicking that the first project needs to be open and if the user clicks the button second time the second instance of first project will open.

Can anyone please tell me what would be the best approach and how should i implement this?

Comment: Please expand on _its not working_

Comment: openExternal is for links, have you tried openPath: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/shell#shellopenpathpath

Comment: @Nick.Mc When I tried using shell.openExternal it gave me an error that my other app doesn't exist in the application database. with ipcMain I wasn't receiving any messages between the two apps and in defaultprotocolClient it opened the app from the browser not from the other electron app.

but I think main problem is that I want to implement it from the start and for that what would be the best approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Deep links](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/launch-app-from-url-in-another-app) which register a custom protocol for your app.